# Laravel 4 - Undefined Property when retrieving a field value which belongsTo another table

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the 'name' field of the 'users' table in my Articles (REST) controller.
These are my models:

```
// models/Article.php

class Article extends Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    protected $table = 'articles';

    public function user(){

    return $this->belongsTo('User','user_id');
    }

    public function upload(){

    return $this->has_one('Upload');
    }
}


// models/User.php

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;


    protected $fillable = array('email','password','name');

    public function articles(){

    return $this->hasMany('Article','user_id');
    }

    /**
    * Get the unique identifier for the user.
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
      return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
      return $this->password;
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
      return $this->email;
    }

    /**
    * The database table used by the model.
    *
    * @var string
    */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
    * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
}



// controllers/ArticlesController.php

class ArticlesController extends \BaseController {
    public function index() // GET (all)
    {
        $articles =  Article::all();
        foreach ($articles as $article) {
            // ** ERROR ** Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$id
            var_dump("title: ".$article->titulo." | user: ".$article->user()->id .' | email: '.$article->user()->email );
        }
    }

    // other functions [....]
}
```

So..How can I get the fields from 'users' table properly?? I've been searching in the Laravel doc and this web and... I haven't' found the error :(

I've set up the database relationships on the migrations files and I've checked out the mysql databases relations diagram and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the keys properly. `belongsTo`'s second parameter should be the local key whereas `hasMany`'s second parameter is the foreign key.

Comment: Yes, I have
// articles (table)

id(PK) bigint unsigned,
title,
description,
user_id(FK) bigint unsigned


// users (table)

id(PK) bigint unsigned,
email,
name

Comment: Try this `$this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');`